# SQL Server 2008 R2: Select statement within REPLACE()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables as shown below:

Table1 : `Test1`

```
Create table Test1
(
  name varchar(50) 
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into Test1 values('a$xyz');  
insert into Test1 values('xyz$a');
```

Table2 : `Test2`

```
create table Test2
(
  pattern varchar(50)
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into Test2 values('a$');
insert into Test2 values('$a');
```

Now I want to `update` the table `Test1`. Specifically I want to update the name in the table by replacing the pattern of table `Test2`.

Like:

```
update Test2
set name = replace(name,'a$','');
```

How can I get the `string_to_replace` from the table `Test2`? As per my knowledge we can't use `SELECT` within `REPLACE` function.

Comment: What are you replacing exactly? What will Table 1 look like after updating?

Comment: @shree.pat18, I am replacing name `a$xyz` to `xyz`. But I want to take `string_to_replace` from table `Test2` in which I will get `a$` and want to replace with empty string `''`.

Comment: So this has to happen for every pattern that can match? Meaning if Test2 had another row 'yz', that should also be replaced?

Comment: @shree.pat18, Yup! Exactly what I want.

Comment: @MAK : May be this can help [Recursive replace from a table of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037168/recursive-replace-from-a-table-of-characters)?

Comment: @MAK check updated script please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will only update each row once.

Create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_test
(
   @a varchar(50)
) 
returns varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @a = replace(@a, pattern, '') 
  FROM test2
  RETURN @a
END
```

Call it like this:

```
UPDATE test1
SET name = dbo.f_test(name)
```

EDIT:

Instead of updating all rows, this may be more effective since it only updates the relevant rows:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT name, dbo.f_test(name) namenew
  FROM test1
)
UPDATE CTE
SET name = namenew
WHERE name <> namenew
```

Comment: Okay! Got it. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: @MAK it was an interesting challange i had not seen before. I hope you get more upvotes

Comment: :) will see. Me too hoping the same.

Comment: The function is taking much more time for execution. I have 5 millions of records the script is still running. The current time is 4 hrs.

Comment: @MAK is other posted the loop methods faster, than this method ? Deepanshu Kalra could work faster, let me know. I would imagine the reason this script isn't fast is that you are updating 5 mil rows and the transaction log is having problems handling it.

Comment: Okay! Let me try Deepanshu Kalra's script.

Comment: Both script are taking more time. It's 20 hrs still running.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHILE ( 1 = 1 ) 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE Test1 
      SET    Test1.NAME = Replace(Test1.NAME, Test2.pattern, '') 
      FROM   Test1, 
             Test2 
      WHERE  ( Test1.NAME LIKE '%' + Test2.pattern + '%' ) 

      IF @@rowcount = 0 
        BREAK 
  END 

SELECT * 
FROM   Test1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eda97/3)**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Update t1
set t1.name = replace(name,t2.pattern,'')
from Test1 t1 , Test2 t2
where t1.name like '%'+t2.pattern+'%'

select * from Test1
```

check sqlfiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eda97/6

Comment: This will only work if there is only 1 match, if there is more than 1 match, it will not update all matches

Answer (score 1):

Or, using a cursor to run through all the replaces multiple times:

```
DECLARE @pat varchar(8)
DECLARE patc CURSOR FOR SELECT pattern FROM test2
OPEN patc
FETCH NEXT FROM patc INTO @pat
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 UPDATE test1 SET name=REPLACE(name,@pat,'')
 FETCH NEXT FROM patc INTO @pat 
END

SELECT * FROM test1
```

Maybe a bit "much" code, but it works, see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7289c/2

The previous solutions by Deepanshu Kalra and Mukund do work fine for your given example, as at most one of the patterns is found in each case. For the more general case where several patterns might be found (and applied) to a single word the `cursor` approach is the more general solution.

Comment: Yeah! looks like more code. But still a good solution. Thank you so much.