# Reformatting and editing nested JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I was building a query builder in Angular UI project using the [Angular-QueryBuilder](https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/) and was building complex queries as similar to the [Demo](https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/demo/) .

I have saved the query which was build in the UI and saved the same in the SQL server database in the JSON format. Saving in database and retrieving from database for the Angular UI is working as expected. JSON Table structure is as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE RuleJSON AS TABLE 
          (RulesetID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ClientID int,   
           RulesJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
          )
```

Attaching the sample JSON which was saved in the SQL table for the reference.

```
{
  "condition": "and",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "100",
      "operator": "=",
      "value": "TEST1"
    },
    {
      "condition": "or",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "2",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "field": "2",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "condition": "and",
          "rules": [
            {
              "field": "ABC.X1",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "field": "ABC.X1",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "condition": "and",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "31",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": "A"
        },
        {
          "field": "31",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": "B"
        },
        {
          "condition": "or",
          "rules": [
            {
              "field": "2",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": 3
            },
            {
              "field": "2",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "condition": "or",
          "rules": [
            {
              "field": "2",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": 5
            },
            {
              "field": "2",
              "operator": "=",
              "value": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "12",
      "operator": "!=",
      "value": "city"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now with this criteria JSON, Ineed to make another API call to my internal project and need to get user data based on the query JSON. But the JSON nodes for the internal project is different from the database saved JSON structure. Attaching the JSON format which is required for the API.

```
{
  "querycondition": "and",
  "queryrules": [
    {
      "queryparametername": "UserData.100",
      "operatorType": "Equals",
      "value": "TEST1"
    },
    {
      "querycondition": "or",
      "queryrules": [
        {
          "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
          "operatorType": "Equals",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
          "operatorType": "Equals",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "querycondition": "and",
          "queryrules": [
            {
              "queryparametername": "ClassData.ABC.X1",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "queryparametername": "ClassData.ABC.X1",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "querycondition": "and",
      "queryrules": [
        {
          "queryparametername": "UserData.31",
          "operatorType": "Equals",
          "value": "A"
        },
        {
          "queryparametername": "UserData.31",
          "operatorType": "Equals",
          "value": "B"
        },
        {
          "querycondition": "or",
          "queryrules": [
            {
              "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": 3
            },
            {
              "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "querycondition": "or",
          "queryrules": [
            {
              "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": 5
            },
            {
              "queryparametername": "UserData.2",
              "operatorType": "Equals",
              "value": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queryparametername": "AddressData.12",
      "operatorType": "notEquals",
      "value": "city"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where following changes are required in the API JSON

1. condition node name need to change to `querycondition`.
2. rules node name should be changed to `queryrules`.
3. field node should be changed to `queryparametername` and need to append `queryname` (from the field data table such as 'UserData','ClassData' and 'AddressData' based on the 'field'node in JSON and field table)
4. operator should be changed to `operatorType` and "=" should be replaced as "Equals" and "!=" as "notEquals".

Sample format and for the `fielddata` table is shown below

```
CREATE TABLE FIELDDATA 
          (ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
           FieldID     VARCHAR(300),
           FieldName   VARCHAR(300),
           QueryName   VARCHAR(300)
          )
INSERT INTO FIELDDATA(FieldID,FieldName,QueryName)
VALUES
('100', 'FirstName', 'UserData.100'),
('2', 'AGE', 'UserData.2'),
('ABC.X1','CLASS','ClassData.ABC.X1'),
('31','INITIAL','UserData.31'),
('12','CITY','AddressData.12')
```

How can I achieve this tried to get the saved JSON with `OPENJSON` and tried to join `FIELDDATA` but due to nested JSON structure nothing worked. I am trying to create the JSON from the stored procedure.

Here is my SQL queries which I have tried,

```
DECLARE @RuleJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @RuleJSON='{ "condition": "and", "rules": [ { "field": "100", "operator": "=", "value": "TEST1" }, { "condition": "or", "rules": [ { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 1 }, { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 2 }, { "condition": "and", "rules": [ { "field": "ABC.X1", "operator": "=", "value": "1" }, { "field": "ABC.X1", "operator": "=", "value": "2" } ] } ] }, { "condition": "and", "rules": [ { "field": "31", "operator": "=", "value": "A" }, { "field": "31", "operator": "=", "value": "B" }, { "condition": "or", "rules": [ { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 3 }, { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 4 } ] }, { "condition": "or", "rules": [ { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 5 }, { "field": "2", "operator": "=", "value": 6 } ] } ] }, { "field": "12", "operator": "!=", "value": "city" } ] }'
SELECT @RuleJSON

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@RuleJSON)
          WITH ( condition   VARCHAR(50),
                rules       NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
          CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( rules ) 
          WITH (
             field  NVARCHAR(500) '$.field'
             , operator NVARCHAR(500)'$.operator'
             , value NVARCHAR(500)'$.value'
             , rules NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
             )
```

Alternatively I tried the following scripts for parsing nested JSON structure.

```
DECLARE @RulesData AS TABLE 
(
    ParentId VARCHAR(MAX),
    Id   VARCHAR(MAX),
    Node VARCHAR(MAX),
    value VARCHAR(MAX),
    Type INT,
    IsLeaf BIT,
    Depth INT,
    Seq BIGINT
 )

;with nodes as 
  (
    select 
      [key] ParentId, 
      [key] Id, 
      [key] Node, 
      [value] Val, 
      [type] Type, 
      isnull( abs( isjson( [value] ) -1 ), 1 ) IsLeaf,
      1 Depth,
      convert( bigint, 1 ) Seq
    from
      openjson( @j ) j 
    union all
    select
      nodes.Id, 
      nodes.Id + '.' + j.[key],
      j.[key], 
      j.[value], 
      j.[type],
      isnull( abs( isjson( j.[value] ) -1 ), 1 ),
      nodes.Depth + 1,
      row_number() over( partition by nodes.Id order by nodes.Id )
    from
      nodes
      outer apply
      openjson( nodes.Val ) j
    where
      isjson( nodes.Val ) = 1
  )
 INSERT INTO @RulesData (ParentId, Id, Node,value,Type,IsLeaf,Depth,Seq)
 select
    ParentId,
    Id,
    Node,
    Val,
    Type,
    IsLeaf,
    Depth,
    Seq
  from 
    nodes

    --WHERE nodes.Type=1 --and nodes.IsLeaf=1   
    
    UPDATE RD SET RD.value=FD.QueryName
    FROM @RulesData RD LEFT JOIN @FIELDDATA FD ON RD.value=FD.FieldID AND RD.Node='field'
    WHERE RD.Node='field'

    UPDATE @RulesData SET Node='querycondition' WHERE  Node='condition'
    UPDATE @RulesData SET Node='queryrules' WHERE  Node='rules'
    UPDATE @RulesData SET Node='queryparametername' WHERE  Node='field'
    UPDATE @RulesData SET Node='operatorType' WHERE  Node='operator'

    SELECT * FROM @RulesData
```

But stuck in creating JSON back from the parsed table.

Tried to create nested from the same table. but on what basis we can do that?

```
;WITH GetLeafLevel AS 
    (
        SELECT  Seq,           
                1 AS lvl,
                (   SELECT  Node,                      
                            value
                    FROM    @RulesData RD               
                    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
                ) AS JSON_Rules
        FROM    @RulesData
        WHERE   Seq = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RD.Seq,
                GetLeafLevel.lvl + 1,
                (   SELECT  Node,                        
                            value
                    FROM    @RulesData
                    --WHERE   RS.RulesetID = Ruleset.RulesetID
                    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
                )
        FROM    @RulesData RD   
                INNER JOIN GetLeafLevel ON RD.Seq = GetLeafLevel.Seq
                WHERE   RD.Seq > 1
    )
    SELECT * FROM GetLeafLevel;
```

I am confused on Parsing the JSON Data to the Table format (where the nesting will come dynamically based on Angular UI) Is the above approach is correct?
And how to generate JSON back for the API operation? Tried to self join the parsed table but stuck on logic. Please help on the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free contract coding service. Even if it didn't work, please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74833807/edit) your question to show the code did you try to use. Why do you think it didn't work?

Comment: Aside... according to your example JSON the last FieldData row should be `('12','CITY','AddressData.12')` instead of `('12','CITY','AddressData.31')`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning : sure I will add the sql query which I have tried. It was not working i will add the same

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: i have updated the question with queries i have tried

Comment: It will almost certainly be easier to do this in any language _other_ than TSQL. Since you're using asp.net, why not retrieve the JSON data into your server-side code, transform it with C# or VB, and then send it on its way from there?

Comment: My suggestion would be to get hold of Newtonsoft's [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for your .NET project, retrieve the original JSON from the database, and use their LINQ support to construct the JSON you'll actually need. You can then make a call to your internal project from there, or pass it down to the Angular to do it.

Comment: @AnnL. was preferring SQL to do the same. But if it is not easy then need to check other options as you have suggested. But in c# also how will handle this nested structure properly without deadlock scenarios?

Comment: @Ken Kin any thoughts on this

Comment: By "deadlock" are you talking about SQL server deadlock scenarios? I don't see why that would be likely to happen: you'd grab the JSON from the table and then return it to the calling program, just as happens with any other form of data.  You wouldn't need to leave the connection open. Were you referring to something different?

Answer (score 0):

Why parse JSON? Why not use a simple string search and replace?

```
SELECT @RuleJSON = REPLACE( @RuleJSON, FieldID, QueryName )
FROM FIELDDATA
```

To make it less prone to false positives I suggest to use this:

```
SELECT @RuleJSON = REPLACE( @RuleJSON, '"field": "' + FieldID + '"', '"field": "' + QueryName + '"' )
FROM FIELDDATA
```

Credit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006282/6305294